# User Breakpoint Called From Code At 0X7c90120120e

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, assembly, breakpoints

I'm debugging a code in VS that I wrote in C.
For some reason, at some point it jumps to an assembly window with the following line:

```
  int        3
```

And a pop up message box appears with the following message:

```
  User Breakpoint Called From Code At  0X7c90120120e
```

I looked at the stack, and the command that caused that was **MALLOC** !

In output window:

```
Heap missing last entry in committed range near 22549c0
```

The weird thing is, when I press OK at the message then F5 to continue debugging it continues and everything **works 100%**. But when I try to execute the code I get a message that my project encountered some problem.

I tried cleaning my project, rebuilding, removing all breakpoints .. nothing worked.

Comment: Can you show the code please?

Comment: Are you using `new` or `malloc`?

Comment: @duDE, The problem is that I cant. It is a very very long code. I forgot to mention that the problem encounters on different lines in the code, but all of them are "Malloc". In addition, the message sometimes appears on some line and sometimes doesn't - on the same line.

Comment: @SanthoshPai thanks for your answer, please check the comment above.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'm using malloc.

Comment: int 3 is a way VS uses to set breakpoints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385370/user-breakpoint-from-nowhere You need to show us some code - you almost certainly are stepping into invalid memory

Comment: @doctorlove How is it possible to step into a invalid memory if I am using Malloc?

Comment: It is a diagnostic you get from the debug heap built into Windows.  Automatically turned on when you use a debugger.  It tells you that your program is corrupting the heap.  This is a very common bug, induced by having undefined behavior in your code.

Comment: Smells like corrupted memory management.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all thank you all for commenting/ answering.

I solved the problem. I found out that I was trying to Free the same memory TWICE.

The reason that I didn't notice it before is that the "Free" (delete function) wasn't in the same function nor the same file as where the debugger stopped/ the breakpoint occured(on malloc).

So if anyone is having the same problem, just make sure you are not Free-ing the same memory more than once.

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of this stack overflow  [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385370/user-breakpoint-from-nowhere).And here's an explanation of this problem in this [link](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/debug-problems-visual-c-6-0-a-t2112400.html).Hope that helps you out.

Comment: The first link seems to be to this discussion. Did you mean something else?

Comment: @SanthoshPai about the first link, I saw it and read the answer and it didnt help me, I also checked in google but didnt find anything that could help, every question was about Free/assert not malloc, which is the wierd, because malloc only allocates memory and returns a pointer, there is no way that I accesed an invalid address. About the SECOND link, thank you, I will check if it helps me.

Comment: Refer this link too http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/user-breakpoint-called-help-7403942.html